# Has anyone tried dell xps 13 9350, ubuntu 16.04 LTS with HP Pavilion 27xw 27-in IPS LED Backlit Monitor

Tags: dell, monitor, display-resolution

Maximum supported resolution on the monitor is 1920 x 1080 . I am able to set the ma resolution to 1280x720 . Is there a way we can improve it. Apparently HP supports only windows.